# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing with Smooth Scroll Script

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, smooth-scrolling

I'm using the Bootstrap Navbar on a one-page website and each anchor is linked to a section on the page. I'm using a very simple javascript to smooth scroll to each section, however this somehow conflicts the collapse function of the navbar - when I click on a link it doesn't collapse anymore which is annoying. I first thought it might be a HTML problem (solved here: [Bootstrap Navbar Collapse not closing on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472815/bootstrap-navbar-collapse-not-closing-on-click) ) but figured out it is a JS problem - any ideas?

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default mainbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hvr-bounce-to-bottom collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#link1" class="navelement">Link 1</a></li>

         <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#link2" class="navelement">Link 2</a></li>

       </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var corp = $("html, body");
  $(".navelement").click(function() {
    var flag = $.attr(this, "href");
    corp.animate({
        scrollTop: $(schild).offset().top - 60
    }, 1600, function() {
        window.location.hash = flag;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: not now, cant find it...

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery :not selector-utility

e.g.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#], [data-toggle=collapse])').click(function(){...})
```

or in your example:

```
var corp = $("html, body");
  $(".navelement:not([data-toggle=collapse])").click(function() {
    var flag = $.attr(this, "href");
    corp.animate({
        scrollTop: $(schild).offset().top - 60
    }, 1600, function() {
        window.location.hash = flag;
    });
    return false;
});
```